# Deploying WAR to AWS Tomcat 404 Error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war

I am trying to deploy a WAR file compiled in JDK 1.8 to an AWS Tomcat Elastic Beanstalk instance. the elastic beanstalk instance uses JDK 8 and Tomcat 8, so I don't understand why I'm getting 404 errors when deploying my WAR file. I'm using gradle to build and WAR the application if that is of any help.

the logs are too big to paste in, and I don't know what is significant, so I uploaded the bundled zip to my dropbox that you can find here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1ssmz76pbqkn20/BundleLogs-1487348401257.zip?dl=0

my web.xml is also too long to paste in the question, so I will link to it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4m7v3fhcczs0ina/web.xml?dl=0

I know it's bad practice to give links on Stack Overflow because of their mutability, so once the solution is found I will edit the question to directly include the pertinent segments of code.

Comment: Does that same war run on your local machine? Are all of your dependencies captured in gradle and not on your local classpath? Also are you trying to deploy it as the ROOT webapp or just your-website.com/webapp or just your-website.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is pretty straight forward:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 477; columnNumber: 23; Error at (477, 23) : The servlets named [TextHistoryServlet] and [TextHistoryServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/TextHistoryServlet] which is not permitted
```

Around that line you'll see:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CsvParseServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CsvParseServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TextHistoryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TextHistoryServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TextHistoryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TextHistoryServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SurveyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SurveyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Remove the second mapping for TextHistoryServlet

Comment: Thank you so much for the dead on response. I saw quite a few errors in the logs, and thought the issue was more problematic than that, but this did the trick!

Answer (score 6):

I am not too sure if this solved your issue. I had a similar issue and it was fixed after extending SpringBootServletInitializer. This is deone because my application runs using Tomcat 8, Java 8 platform, which is like a container. Generally you need to extends SpringBootServletInitializer when deploying a war in a container.

Here is a sample Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```